# Need to right align in list number without using ol tag

Tags: html, css

I have a normal paragraph:

HTML:

```
<p><span>[1]</span> list-type-1</p>
<p><span>[2]</span> list-type-2</p>
...
<p><span>[10]</span> list-type-3</p>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  text-align:right;
}
```

Need Output:

```
 [1] list-type-1
 [2] list-type-2
....
[10] list-type-10
```

But the list numbers are placed on left. So, how to fix right align.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is within the same <p> so you won't be able to change this as you wish. cannot you change simply the order and do something like <p>list-type-3</p><span>[10]</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up span's width ie:

```
span {
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/50tp475k/

Answer (score 2):

Modify your css like this

```
span {
    text-align:right;
    float:right;   // This style is responsible to put your list numbers on right side in your case
}
```

see Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5mmgu9dk/

Answer (score 1):

alternative

```css
p{
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>[1]</span> list-type-1</p>
<p><span>[2]</span> list-type-2</p>
<p><span>[23]</span> list-type-23</p>
<p><span>[10]</span> list-type-3</p>
```